# what's the utility of signals and slots

Tags: c++, qt, boost, qtcore, qt-signals

Actually I have been using signals and slots while programing in Qt.
The main use of signals and slots are in the UI interaction, for example a clicked button sends a signal that will invoke a slot to perform action.
I know that it's possible to use signals and slots for non-gui application, for example a server side application.
I looked for other libraries that offers signal and slots and I found [boost](http://boost.org) library. It's some how different from what I learned from Qt.
And then I was wondering what's the real utility of signals and slots, since I can manually call a function to perform an action at a given time.

for example in boost here is an example of signals/slots :

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void mySlot(){
  std::cout << "I'm a slot" << std::endl;
}

void main(){
  boost::signals2::signal<void ()> sig;
  // Connecting the slot to the signal.
  sig.connect(mySlot);

  // Emitting a signal that will call mySlot 
  sig();

  return 0;
}
```

I could simply do the same thing with a simple call of `mySlot()` isn't it ?

Not that what made me think is that when we try to connect two different slots, they are called in the same order than connection. and if the first slot is blocking ( try to add an infinite loop) the second slots will never be called ! I guess that it's a kind of vector that stores the addresses of the functions and then iterate the loop and call one by one !

What's the magic behind the signals and slots ? or it's only a kind of abstraction for the developer ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How would you call a slot from a library that would be defined in an application?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question can you reformulate please ?

Comment: Using signal/slot reduces the coupling (so easier to unit-test), and invert the dependency.

Comment: @nos: my point was, you could not do that without signals/slots without further actions in which case you will end up having signals and slots. :)

Comment: The lesson I think is not to take simple example code as a real-world use case... but instead to extrapolate it to how such a pattern, made sufficiently more complex to actually be useful, could enable better designs and/or cleaner code in a real-world scenario. Which signals and slots (the general idea, not just Qt's version) **really** can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In short*: The main idea is **decoupling** in my opinion.

*In longer*: With direct function calls, you could not have a well-separate establishment between the common functionality and the clients of it, for instance. There would be a tight coupling unlike with signals and slots because you would need to know at the point of some condition meeting your criteria which methods exactly to call.

If you would like to gain more freedom, like with many other OOP design patterns, you need something like signals and slots. When a common component, let us call it a library, emits a signal, it does not have to be aware of the (potentially not-yet-existing) client interfaces. This makes the common component flexible enough.

It will also keep responsiveness of the application better since it is not a direct call, but processed by the Qt event loop. Arguably, you could circumvent this with custom threading mechanisms, but that would be lotta more work to make it safe enough, and you would end up doing something close this in the end of the day.

Comment: Note that `Boost.Signals2` library does not introduce any loops/thread (as opposed to Qt) - slots just get invoked synchronously.

Comment: @IgorR.: I do not seem to have written that Boost.Signals2 does.

Answer (score -1):

Signals and slots are simply a communication mechanism that can be used across different threads of execution. That is the main value (especially in a GUI focussed library such as QT). Usually there is 1 thread responsible for drawing and managing the graphical side of the application and 1 or more worker threads. Using signals and slots it is possible to abstract away from this. If you wanted to use direct function calls you'd need to synchronise the threads which would lead to reduced performance and responsiveness on the GUI side.

Indeed within one execution thread it does not make much sense using signals and slots. The value comes in when you want to communicatie between processes (on the same machine or between different machines).

Comment: I disagree that that is the main value of signals and slots. Decoupling is more valuable.

Comment: Also, not all signal/slot libraries are thread-safe... so that's not their inherent definition as you seem to be saying. The point is implementing a design pattern, not being usable across different threads.